# Socket-io Client Issue When Switching To Typescript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, sockets

I am trying to take a template I have for the MERN stack + Socket.io and migrate to Typescript. I am having issues when I change the client to Typescript.

Problem:My client pings from socket.io-client do not reach the server and I get pongs back from seemingly nowhere.

Server: For the server side, I cd into my server and run npm start = node dist/app.js

Server code: dist/app.ts

```
import { Mongoose } from "mongoose";
import express from "express";
import { Socket } from "socket.io";
const app=express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const path = require('path');
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI|| "";
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const mongoose: Mongoose = require('mongoose');


mongoose.connect(uri, {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'build')));

io.on('connection', (socket: Socket) => {

    socket.on('ping',(msg)=>{
        console.log(msg)
        socket.emit('pong')
    })

 console.log("A user has connected")
});

http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

Client: I have a boilerplate react project with my code in client/src/app.tsx. I run npm start = react-scripts start.

Client code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import config from './config';
const io=require('socket.io-client')
const PORT=config[process.env.NODE_ENV].endpoint
const socket = io(PORT);
console.log(PORT)
const App: React.FC = () => {

  const [clicked,setClicked] = useState(false)
  useEffect(()=> {
    socket.on('pong', ()=>
    console.log("pong"));
  });
   
  function handleClick() {
    console.log("click")
    
    socket.emit('ping')
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={()=> handleClick()}>
        {clicked? "ON": "OFF"}
      </button>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the client tsconfig.json since I suspect the problem is client side. (I ran my server against non-ts code and had no issue with my sockets).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

The output:

On the client console, I get that my port (which is my proxy in package.json) is http://localhost:5000. I also get a series of "pongs" very slowly (Every 15s), totally unrelated to my clicks. Really unclear how this is happening, hopefully I am doing something very silly.

On the server, I just see "A user has connected" whenever I connect, no pongs.

I've tried a lot of things, including using non-functional components, to no avail. It's unclear to me how to debug this, it's just worked in the past. Clearly the server and client are communicating, but the sockets are really not.

All suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ping` and `pong` are reserved `Socket.IO` events ([source](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/), at the bottom of the page), meaning you can't use them yourself. You should instead use some other event names.

As for why it worked before... I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: Wow okay, this is news to me. 

To be clear and transparent, I mean something similar worked before. Not ping and pong. I stripped it down to this simple example because it would be "easier". 

Will try something else, thanks!

Comment: Yup, that was it. 

Indeed my old project was too big to turn to tsx in one piece, so I just stripped out the functionality and tried to build it back up starting with the easiest example I could think of. Quite funny that I managed to pick these forbidden events! 

Thanks so much, this bug killed 2 weekends for me!

Answer (score 0):

I think Take-Some-Bytes answered the reason for why the pongs come back in an unexpected way, but I think the reason why you got multiple pongs could be because the `useEffect` doesn't have a dependency list (which causes the effect to run on each update). The `socket.on` could have been called multiple times thus running the `console.log` multiple times on a `pong` event.

Also, I personally have never tried doing the `io.connect` (or the `io(url)` thing) outside of the component life cycle. Not sure if that has anything to do with this, but I would put the `io.connect` in the `useEffect` and store the socket using `useRef`. Something like:

```js
  const socketRef = useRef<...>(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io(PORT);
    socketRef.current = socket;
    socket.on('server', () => console.log("server"));
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I also implemented this simultaneously with the suggestion above and it works great.